# Lag colum by group in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, window-functions

I have data frame `mydata` such as the following:

```
  col1 col2
1    1    1
2    1    2
3    1    3
4    2    1
5    2    2
6    2    3
```

Y want to lag `col2` within groups in `col1`, so my expected result would be as follwing:

```
  col1 col2
1    1    NA
2    1    1
3    1    2
4    2    NA
5    2    1
6    2    2
```

Follwing the procedure from [this answer][1] I try

```
with_lagged_col2 = 
  mydata %>% group_by(col1) %>% arrange(col1) %>% 
  mutate(laggy = dplyr::lag(col2, n = 1, default = NA))
```

And what I actually get is

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   col1 [2]
   col1  col2 laggy
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1    NA
2     1     2     1
3     1     3     2
4     2     1     3
5     2     2     1
6     2     3     2
```

Why is `group_by` being ignored here?

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. I get the intended result when I run your code. Can you try in a fresh R session and see if it still doesn't work for you?

Comment: I worked in a fresh R session, so I tried mydata = data.frame(col1 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), col2 = c(1,2,3,1,2,3))
with_lagged_col2 = 
  mydata %>% dplyr::group_by(col1) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(laggy = dplyr::lag(col2, n = 1, default = NA)) and it worked as well...

Comment: @thelateemail the reason why `group_by` did not work as intended. It may be a conflict with `plyr`. The OP load `plyr` with `dplyr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that arrange:

```
with_lagged_col2 = 
  mydata %>% group_by(col1) %>% # groups data by col1
  mutate(laggy = dplyr::lag(col2, n = 1, default = NA)) # creates new lagged variable of col1, the missing value i.e. first row is NA
```

Comment: Right, but it still won't work for me without the arrange...

Comment: dput(mydata) your data

Comment: > dput(mydata)
structure(list(col1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), col2 = c(1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3)), .Names = c("col1", "col2"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: It's working on a fresh R session. I think it was namespace conflict.

Comment: I would recommend require(dplyr) and do not use  dplyr::lag. Just use "lag" instead.

Comment: @AleksandrVoitov, could you please add explanation in your solution too, which function is doing which thing please.