# How to create lagged differences by group in R?

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2"), 
                 x = c(12, 20, 24, 10, 14))

id   x
 1  12
 1  20
 1  24
 2  10
 2  14
```

I'd like to obain the lagged differences of `x` per `id`. The expected result:

```
id   x
 1  12
 1   8
 1   4
 2  10
 2   4
```

A `dplyr` solution is preferable.

Note that this question is not a duplicate, since the group refers to an ID in my case, not an unordered category.

Comment: How can this not be a duplicate? What do you mean by "the group refers to an ID, not an unordered category"? [Lag colum by group in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454717/lag-colum-by-group-in-dplyr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `diff`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(x = c(x[1], diff(x)), .by = id)
  id  x
1  1 12
2  1  8
3  1  4
4  2 10
5  2  4
```